# How to import a transaction matrix into Python?

Tags: python, pandas

How to import a transaction matrix into Python?

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("...data.csv", header=None, sep=",", keep_default_na=False, na_values= None )
df.head()
```

Returns:
[image]

But I'm trying to achieve this:

```
In: print(records[0])
Out: ['citrus fruit', 'semi-finished bread', 'margarine', 'ready soups']
```

Trying this and many other things:

```
num_linhas = df.shape[0]
num_colunas = df.shape[1]

records = []
for i in range(0, num_linhas):
  for j in range(0, num_colunas):
    if len(df.iloc[i,j]) > 0:
      records.append(df.values[i,j])
```

Which is returning:

```
In: print(records[0])
Out: citrus fruit
```

Comment: You can specify the number of rows with head: `df.head(1)` for only the first row

Comment: if you want to read line by line you may csv module 

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/reading-csv-files

Comment: @Zerox num_colunas = 32 and num_linhas=9835

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df.T[0]
```

or

```
df.iloc[0,:]
```